# Cut deletes all contents of my file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cut

When I am using the `cut` command in linux, and redirecting the output to the same file, it seems to delete the contents of my file. What I am doing is:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file1.txt > file1.txt
```

My goal is to cut out all columns from the file, except for the first column and save changes to the file that I am working with. But when I do this, and open my file, I am left with a blank file. However, when I specify a different file, the command seems to work perfectly fine.

When I run:

`cut {some command} FILE1.txt > FILE2.txt`

This seems to work fine.

Is there a way that I can specify that I want the changes from my `cut` command to be overwritten on to my current working file?

Comment: The shell has to fork and open `stdin` and `stdout` before exec'ing `cut`.  Unsurprisingly, opening the file for overwrite (before it gets `dup2`'d to `stdout`) erases all the contents.  And this happens before `cut` gets to read from its `stdin`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36261/can-i-read-and-write-to-the-same-file-in-linux-without-overwriting-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary file with the desired changes and then rename it to the target file name:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file1.txt > file1.txt.temp
mv file1.txt.temp file1.txt
```